# How to create a transparant overlay effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, overlay

After several Google searches and searching the forum, I'm looking for simple, lightweight and easy way to create a clear glass overlay. I've attached an image that shows the clarity. It's easy to do in CSS but I can't figure out how to do it in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: How do you do it in CSS?

Comment: @horatio check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437910/glass-transparent-css-effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a rectangle filled with a color.

Reduce the rectangle's layer **opacity** in the **Layers Panel**.

Done.

Comment: In the image above, for best practice; Should the rectangle that is filled with color be a higher value or lower value than the background image?

Comment: It depends upon the highlight you want. If you want a lighter area use a lighter color, if you want it darker, use a darker color. The image above uses a darker color.